# interact.js cannot drag an object tag SVG

Tags: svg, interact.js

I was trying to move a svg object by drag/drop/scale/rotate and touch functionality. My SVG is enclosed in `<object>` tag which it seems to be not working fine with the interact.js. I had coded the test whereby an in-line SVG can be dragged..
http://jsfiddle.net/calvinv99/gm13f4t1/1/

```
<object class=draggable data="http://perlmaven.com/img/red_blue_circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Whereas the object SVG does not work.

is this a restriction by the interact.js that it only works with inline SVGs?
is there a workaround?

Comment: doesnt work for me neither. tried adding the interact only after the object's svg is loaded, but that doesnt seem to help either...will stick with online for the moment.

Comment: as far as I can see, when using object, the svg is treated more like an iframe (not LIKE an iframe, but the behaviour is somewhat similar..). for example, when wanting to access it's nodes with js/jquery, I had to use `$('object').get(0).contentDocument`, this is what you do when accessing an iframe's contents as well...so, the object's svg's DOM seems to be disconnected from the main HTML DOM. When having an inline svg, CSS rules from the HTML also apply, wich is a big advantage as well.

Comment: not "online", but "inline"...